# what to do with fraction as index number

Tags: indexing

given these inputs x = 4, S = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10], and n = 10

```
     search (x,S,n) {
         i = 1
         j = n
         while i < j {
             m = [(i+j)/2]
             if x > Sm then i=n+1
             else j = m
         end
         if x = Si then location = i
         else location = 0
```

This code is not from any particular language its just from my discrete math hw, but I'm confused as to what Sm would equal on the first iteration because m would be 11/2. If i use a fraction as the index do I round down? Is there a general rule for this? Am I making any sense? Help pls

Comment: Perhaps, you could ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com/ or could be migrated to that?

Comment: Actually, http://cs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit.